# Browser simulation - Python

Tags: python, session, browser, cookies

I need to access a few HTML pages through a Python script, problem is that I need COOKIE functionality, therefore a simple urllib HTTP request won't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Several JavaScript-based implementations of Python are available (which can run in a web browser without any additional plugins). Would this be relevant? http://syntensity.com/static/python.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

check out [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/).  "Stateful programmatic web browsing in Python".
It handles cookies  automagically.

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
resp = br.open("http://www.mysitewithcookies.com/")
print resp.info()  # headers
print resp.read()  # content
```

mechanize also exposes the urllib2 API, with cookie handling enabled by default.

Comment: Can be quite slow though, so YMMV.

Comment: Gregg, can you explain?  its basically just a wrapper around urllib2

Comment: Well, when using mechanize, it can be slow, in my experience.  It's pretty to use, and test for yourself :)

Answer (score 3):

The [cookielib module](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html#module-cookielib) provides cookie handling for HTTP clients.

> The [cookielib](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html#module-cookielib)  module defines classes for automatic handling of HTTP cookies. It is useful for accessing web sites that require small pieces of data – cookies – to be set on the client machine by an HTTP response from a web server, and then returned to the server in later HTTP requests.

The examples in the doc show how to process cookies in conjunction with `urllib`:

```
import cookielib, urllib2
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
r = opener.open("http://example.com/")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that does cookies, and as a bonus does authentication for a site that requires a username and password.

```
import urllib2
import cookielib
import string



def cook():
    url="http://wherever"
    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    authinfo = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
    realm="realmName"
    username="userName"
    password="passWord"
    host="www.wherever.com"
    authinfo.add_password(realm, host, username, password)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj), authinfo)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)

    # Create request object
    txheaders = { 'User-agent' : "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)" }
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request(url, None, txheaders)
        cj.add_cookie_header(req)
        f = urllib2.urlopen(req)

    except IOError, e:
        print "Failed to open", url
        if hasattr(e, 'code'):
            print "Error code:", e.code

    else:

        print f
        print f.read()
        print f.info()
        f.close()
        print 'Cookies:'
        for index, cookie in enumerate(cj):
            print index, " : ", cookie      
        cj.save("cookies.lwp")
```

Comment: maybe you should accept the answer, RH, if you this worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try Dryscrape for this:

```
Import dryscrape as d
d.start_xvfb()
Br = d.Session()
Br.visit('http://URL.COM')
#open webpage
Br.at_xpath('//*[@id = "email"]').set('user@enail.com')
#finding input by id
Br.at_xpath('//*[@id = "pass"]').set('pasword') 
Br.at_xpath('//*[@id = "submit_button"]').click()
#put id of submit button and click it
```

You don't need cookie lib to store cookies just install Dryscrape and do it in your style

Comment: Please don't use an answer to promote a different question. That's what bounties are for

Comment: Ok sorry for that but no body answer my question thats why any way sorry again