# How to login to a website by using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to login to a website by using Python script. Please help me

```
url = 'http://12.345.67.891:8000/login'
values = {'username': 'abcdefg',
          'password': 'apple'}

r = requests.post(url, data=values)
print r.content
```

Getting below error when executed the code

```
[{"fieldNames":["User"],"classification":"RequiredError","message":"Required"}]
```

Comment: using paramko you can achieve this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Login on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069524/python-login-on-a-website)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it is expecting `User` not `username`:

```
url = 'http://12.345.67.891:8000/login'
values = {'User': 'abcdefg',
          'password': 'apple'}

r = requests.post(url, data=values)
print(r.content)
```

Comment: I believe the "U" is supposed to be uppercase as it reads in their error. `"User"`

Comment: @Jaba over-speeding, fixed! :D

Comment: By implementing the above code i am getting output as "{"message":"Logged in"}". Does that mean it is logged in?

Comment: @SwethaGorantla indeed, it does!

Comment: Thanks, when i manually browse through the website. Once i logged in it is redirecting to a page which is homepage. In that home page response i can see cookies available which we can use in the further requests. an you please help me to find how to store cookies in a variable from the response of the login page and use it in further requests?

Comment: @SwethaGorantla Indeed, but that is quiet a different question, you can ask another question with the details and consider this one marked if it helped, cheers.